# Nashville to Detroit - which is quicker / the major route?

Tags: usa, driving, routes

Question for those with **local knowledge**,

in the US, when driving from the South to Detroit,

[image]

you can either go on 65 (via Indianapolis region) or on 71/75.

Which is the more major, free-flowing, route? Cheers

Comment: Google Maps does a good job of considering congestion-related time delays, particularly if you do a route at the actual time and day of the week you plan to depart.

Comment: I-65 up to I-75 and going through Ohio, rather than Indiana. There are always slow-downs as you hit the cities, especially the major ones.  I just think the eastern route is easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question #1: Where in Detroit? - city center or suburbs? This is important!(I'm a born and bred Detoit area person.) 
Detroit proper or southern/southwest suburbs - I-75 or maybe I-75 and US 23 depending on where. 
Northern suburbs - Take I-75 to US 23 near Toledo.  This will avoid a lot of traffic (and I believe there also heavy construction on I-75 south of Detroit) and then east on I-94 or I-96/696 depending on where you're heading.
Both 75 and 65 are flat and boring so I'd go for shorter in this case.  There is a MIDrive app for your phone for specific construction info.

Comment: thanks Judy !  NICE POINT.  totally understood.   going to COBO like everyone else.   arriving afternoon.  actually it's incredibly wise you mention this - at one point I was going first to the airport, and perhaps that would have been the other ..................... THANKS

Comment: local knoiwledge == heart of site!

Comment: so for literally downtown, at about noon-2pm, I should take 23 basically through ann arbor and maybe 14.   not 75 through linkin park etc (I see the construction now!)   unreal.

Comment: I don't see my edits so I'll comment here.. Hope it's not a duplicate.  Here's the official detour (http://www.75rougeriver.com/detours.html).  Take either US 23 as mentioned above but go to I96 (east) into the city or take I 275 north of Monroe MI to I96 (east) into the city.  Either way I 96 will take you directly to Cobo Hall - if I recall correctly under it and there are signs directing you to parking.  US 23 is more rural than 275.  275 is heavily suburban but both can, of course, be congested.  Downtown Detroit is much different than its historic reputation and it's great.  Enjoy!!